# How to manage stored credentials (Windows Vault) for another user than you, e.g. SYSTEM?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, credentials

When I go to Credential Manager in Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008, it lets me edit the cached credentials for my account.  Is it possible to edit someone else's stored credentials on the same machine?

For example, I have a scheduled task that runs as SYSTEM and logs into Team Foundation Server using stored credentials.  I set up these credentials by [running cmd.exe as SYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account) and running `tf.exe`, which prompted me for the credentials.  Now SYSTEM has these cached credentials, but I don't know how to clear them if I ever need to.

Comment: Not sure about the answer myself (short of "get their password and log in as them"), but [this question on SuperUser does deal with the same problem](http://superuser.com/q/537697/148034) and the not-accepted answer looks promising.

Answer (score 5):

You may find [`cmdkey.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243.aspx) useful for this purpose. Start with a `cmdkey /list` and proceed from there with the appropriate item for `cmdkey /delete`.

Note that cmdkey itself does only allow to list credentials for the current user, but it should be far easier to get a Command Terminal under a different user account than a complete Desktop session. E.g. use `runas /USER:proper_user cmd.exe` or see [ways to do it for SYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account).